# Regex Pattern for document indexed

Tags: regex, python-3.x

there is a extended document with title indexed in format ascend, for example `8.1`, `8.1.1`... `8.1.1.1.1.1.1`  such as:

```
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.12.1.1.12.1.1 title03</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1 title01</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.1.1.1.1.1 title03</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.1 title02</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.1.1.1.2.1 title03</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.1.1 title03</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.1.3.2.3.1 title03</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.1.1.1 title05</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.4.2.5.9.3 title03</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.1.1.1.1 title06</h1>
<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.11.12.14.3.1 title03</h1>
```

I tried to get only title03 with regex expression `re.search(r'\">\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3} (.*)</h1>',x)` but it matches all of the title without exceptions instead of only matches for `d.d.d.d.d.d.d`

thanks in advance

Comment: [Works](https://regex101.com/r/YccNOj/5) for me

Comment: [Works](https://rextester.com/OVSS41043) for me too although you really should escape the `.`s

Comment: it works when matched for `title03` but for the other return `None`.  because I save in variable `grp = re.search(r'\">\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3} (.*)</h1>',x)` and then getting title03 with `grp[1]`.   The result of None is an error `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
r'">\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){6} (.*)</h1>'
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/V0sp0j/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
re.search(r'\">\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})* (.*)</h1>',x)
```

Comment: It matches with all lines, I meant it matches with `8.1` and `8.1.1` etc.  the result expected is that regex expression only match with lines like `<h1 class="topicTitle-h1">8.1.1.1.1.2.1 title03</h1>` because `Title03` in original document is different for each line matched and original document has 15000+ matches